# Winter Bash 2019 の帽子の説明の翻訳を改善したい

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, winter-bash

[Winter Bash 2019](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/werewolf-hunter) の帽子一覧にある "Werewolf Hunter" の説明が
"どこかのサイト**でで**古い質問3件を編集" となってしまっています。

なお、これらの訳に関する文字列は https://ja.traducir.win や https://www.transifex.com の中には見当たりませんでした。

**2019/12/12時点での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 他の箇所も ja.traducir.win に無かったので調べてみたところ、 [Winter Bash に関するテキストは transfiex や ja.traducir.win では翻訳出来ない](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288311)ようです。

Answer (score 3):

修正が反映されていることを確認しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

@aki さん対応ありがとうございます :-)